# Rspec test readonly model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have small aplication in rails 5. I tried to use Rspec to test it but failed with readonly model.

I have readonly model Product and normal model ProductMsp. The second one a is list of all prices associated to Product and is stored in Rails DB. Product is a external readonly connection with another database to withdraw list of products.

I added association to product to spec/factories/product_msps.rb.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product_msp do
    product_id 11
    initial_date '01-01-2017'
    expiry_date '31-01-2017'
    msp 9999.99
    association :product
  end
end
```

I didn't add any new test. When I run rspec once again I get failures. Probably rspec want to create products, but cannot due to readonly database table.

```
Failures:
    1) ProductMsp Validations initial_date cannot by empty
    Failure/Error: pm = FactoryGirl.build(:product_msp, initial_date: nil)    
        ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord:
            Product is marked as readonly
                 # ./spec/models/product_msp_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Below is failing test: (there is more failures)

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProductMsp, type: :model do
    it 'initial_date cannot by empty' do
      pm = FactoryGirl.build(:product_msp, initial_date: nil)
      pm.valid?
      expect(pm.errors[:initial_date]).to include("can't be blank")
    end
end
```

spec/factories/products.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    id 11
    name 'Porsche Cayenne'
  end
end
```

and app/model/product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'tw_Id'

  def readonly?
    true
  end

  has_many :product_msps

  default_scope {where(product_type:1).order(:name)}
```

A the main question is: How to deal with test and readonly models?

- Is rspec suitable for it?
- Should I get rid of testing readonly models

I searched through internet but I didn't find any examples of such problem. I need to build app on top of another database, but I would like to have it tested somehow. :-)

Comment: Have you tried to add `skip_create` to your `product` factory? I suppose it should help

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It was so easy. I focused on rspec, but solution wasn't there.

Answer (score 5):

(For future searchers:) )

You should add `skip_create` to your factory for the read-only model. That allows avoiding database record creation and should solve the problem for this. It is also useful if you want to create a factory for a class, that is not connected to the database (does not inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base).

Answer (score 4):

You should disable persistence using `skip_create`, per the FactoryGirl (now FactoryBot) [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-methods-to-persist-objects):

```
factory :product do
  skip_create
end
```

You can also run `FactoryGirl.lint` according to the [linting documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories). If one of your factories returns:

```
* product - Product is marked as readonly (ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord)
```

then you know you should use the `skip_create` feature.